# How to use html to draw a face with particles?

Tags: javascript, particles, face

How can I make something like this:

http://highline.huffingtonpost.com/articles/en/the-21st-century-gold-rush-refugees/#/niger

How could the face be drawn with particles as shown in this website? any video tutorial or articles on how to do that? or at least which technologies are used?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick glance over the page source, this seems to be accomplished by using an [animated SVG JavaScript library](http://svgjs.com/).